# How to include CSV file in JMETER running in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gradle, jmeter

I am using Jenkins as my deployment pipeline.  I have a JMETER project that I will be executing in a build step in Jenkins.  That JMETER project has a dependency on a csv file for parameters.  How do I get that file included in the Jenkins pipeline and how do I tell JMETER where to look for it in the csv data set config?

I could also do it via a gradle command if that is an option.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe this could help : https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is [running JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui), the relevant [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) snippet would be:

```
node {
   stage 'Run JMeter Test'
   bat 'c:/jmeter/bin/jmeter.bat -n -t c:/jmeter/extras/Test.jmx -l test.jtl'
}
```

The above setup assumes Windows operating system, if your Jenkins master or [build agent](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds) is running Linux, Unix or MacOSX - just change `bat` to `sh`. You will also need to amend JMeter installation path to reflect your environment. See [Running a JMeter Test via Jenkins Pipeline - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-test-jenkins-pipeline-tutorial) to see example configuration.

In case of command-line non-GUI mode of JMeter execution you need to copy your CSV file(s) to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.

In case of using [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter) - the same approach, drop your CSV file(s) to JMeter's "bin" folder

In case of [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) you will need to copy CSV file(s) to `src/test/jmeter` folder of your Maven project.

And finally you can just use full path(s) (not relative) to CSV file(s) in CSV Data Set Config elements.